# Docker compose no connection between containers using socket

Tags: docker, nginx, magento, docker-compose, fpm

I am trying to use https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento. Following the instructions, the setup includes a nginx container in the frontend, which is suppose to connect with a php-fpm in the backend.

Containers:

```
ubuntu@DESKTOP-HED9HVG:/mnt/c/Users/Me$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
8db110d5737a        markoshust/magento-nginx:1.18-4            "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->8443/tcp                                          localdev_app_1
74ff9e11646a        markoshust/magento-php:7.4-fpm-5           "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          9000-9001/tcp                                                                                localdev_phpfpm_1
```

As far as I can understand the code, the phpfpm is listening on the docker socket.

[Nginx upstream](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/blob/master/images/nginx/1.18/conf/default.magento1.conf):

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server unix:/sock/docker.sock;
}
```

[php-fpm.conf](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/blob/master/images/php/7.4/conf/php-fpm.conf):

```
:
listen = /sock/docker.sock
:
```

this is the [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/blob/master/compose/docker-compose.yml) file

But I can't get it to work.

php-fpm is working:

```
app@74ff9e11646a:~/html$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
app          1  0.0  0.2 222828 33168 ?        Ss   06:57   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
app          6  0.0  0.0 222828 10412 ?        S    06:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
app          7  0.0  0.0 222828 10348 ?        S    06:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
app          8  0.0  0.0 222828 10348 ?        S    06:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
app          9  0.0  0.0 222828 10348 ?        S    06:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

However,from nginx to phpfpm, there is ping, but there is no telnet:

```
/var/www/html # ping phpfpm
PING phpfpm (172.19.0.7): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.7: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.128 m

/var/www/html # telnet phpfpm 9000
telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.19.0.7): Connection refused
/var/www/html # telnet phpfpm 9001
telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.19.0.7): Connection refused
```

I am windows10 wsl2. Any idea what I should check?

Answer (score 1):

You are telling PHP-FPM to use a socket for communication, that's why it's not listening on TCP / port 9000.

It can **either** listen on a TCP Port, **OR** use a socket, not both.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But it didn't work even without the `9000` in the url.